# single session shairing in all browser

Tags: php, session

In my website (php)  I want that if I have created session from IE browser then no need to login if i open site on other browser like mozilla etc in.

Is it possible to share single session on all sites ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-on-cookie

Answer (score 0):

No. Session saves in a browser. You can use coockies for your situation.