# Cookies on multiple browsers in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have an application in ASP.Net  that use cookies for store some information.I want to open a form only first time when a user enter into the site.I created a cookie and I wrote something in that .The next time I enter the site, I read this information,if something is wrote in there that means that it's not necessary to open the form again.It works fine if I use the same browser, but if first I open with Internet Explorer the site  ,I make the cookie , wrote something in it , I close the browser and then I open site  with Mozzila Firefox the application can't see the cookie that i created with Internet Exlorer(the read cookie is null) .I create the cookie with Mozilla , i open application with Chrome , this also doesn't see the cookie.If  I wrote something in the cookie with one browser , I can read this value only if i use the same browser. What should I do to see cookie content  with all the browsers, to can read the cookie content with all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

No! You can't and Check this question [Can two different browser share on cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-on-cookie)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with regular cookies, what I know of. Each browser store and keep track of their own cookies, and does not share them.

I haven't tried it myself, but there are [examples](http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash) where Flash cookies and JavaScript are being used to create something like a cross-browser cookie.