# Are cookies persistent across different browsers?

Tags: php, cookies, browser

Are cookies persistent across different browsers?

To elaborate on the question, let's say we have website that looks for an specific cookie on the user machine. If not found, it will create one. 
Suppose the user quits Chrome and go to the same website on Firefox, will the website locate the same cookie on the user's machine? Or will it create a new one for Firefox?

Comment: Each browser has its own distinct cookie store. (Well, normally.)

Comment: You can easily try this and see for yourself...

Comment: cookie is browser specific  files.   A cookie set when you browse in Netscape Navigator will not be read if you visit the same site again using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your helpful inputs. Since I posted that question, I ran into something called "evercookies" which are suppose to be persistent. Does anyone know if these are used in practice? Why or why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Cookies are stored in browser-specific files.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is a piece of data that is sent from the server (web server) back to the client (browser). There is a contract between the two to that describes when the client should return the cookie back to the server on followup requests. This allows the server to, among other things, identify the client again.

Because each browser is a unique client they are unaware of any cookies that have been set on other browsers.

See this SO question that explains how you could hack around this with flash:

[Can two different browser share one cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-on-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

No, if they are non-persistent cookies they are deleted upon closing the browser and if they are persistent they are saved on the hard drive but are only used by a single browser.

However, you can get around this by saving data to a mysql table and link the user's ip address to the specific data you would have saved in the cookie:

```
$ip = $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ];
```

Comment: IP addresses can change all the time or be identical for two different browsers, they no way uniquely identify a client. Two connections from two machines coming from behind NAT will both have the same outward facing IP for example.

Comment: True, which is why you shouldn't use it as your sole solution. You can use both cookies and a database w/ IP address to handle more situations than cookies alone will, such as switching browsers.

Comment: But if you use IP to handle different browsers, couldn't you easily run into collision with another host machine in the same network?

Comment: Yes, granted that unless you are google, facebook, wikipedia, or some other staple of the internet, that seems unlikely to not be the same person. Also, the same problem arises with cookies, just when two different people get on the same machine at different times.

Comment: @HankLiu In other words, there is no perfect solution to your question, but I did offer you a possible, albeit problematic solution

Comment: I think the likely hood of being same person would actually be very little since most people today uses a private IP address that is sharing a public IP.

Comment: Unless $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] somehow grabs the private IP assigned by the router rather than the public IP provided by the ISP. If this is the case, could you explain how this is even possible? All information in regard to the private IP should be lost after network address translation.