# Click to create cookies, and if cookie exists, add class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to create cookies for all ".article" links when clicked. And also need to add class "visited" to them. So that next time browser comes back to the page, he/she knows what links have been visited. Below is my code:

```
var cookieName = '#read_';

            $('.article').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id'), cookie = cookieName + id;  
                var CookieSet = $.cookie(cookie, 'true');
                if (CookieSet == null) {
                      // Do Nothing
                 }
                if (jQuery.cookie(CookieSet)) {
                    $(cookie).addClass('visited');      
                }
            }).live('click', function(e) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id'), cookie = cookieName + id;                      
                $.cookie(cookie, "true");
            });
```

Not sure cookies were set, but when I clicked a link and then came back to this page, no "visited" class was added.

Comment: Replace cookie in `$(cookie).addClass('visited');` to `this`

Comment: Hi @traditional, I actually need to add class to another list with all  the article name. The structure of it is: <li id="read_123">article one</li>, where "123" is the id of ".article".

Answer (score 0):

if the user only need to know if page was visited, just use `visited` selector in css:

```
.article:visited
{ 
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: But it does not work when the user visits the page with a different browser.

Comment: @Alex you could try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-on-cookie. It is a bit hacky though