# cookies not working in two browsers

Tags: php, cookies

i want to used cookie like this 1. create cookie in firefox browser and 2. i want to access in crome or any other browsers. is it possible using php coding?, thanks!

```
$cookie_name = "refercode";
$rndcode = '123';
setcookie($cookie_name, $rndcode, time() + (86400), "/"); /* 86400 = 1 day */

echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

Comment: Short answer is that you will have to use some kind of permanent datastore. You can not cross Cookies between browsers. Even if you could, imagine the secrurity issues with that!

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, every browser maintains and has access to its own cookies only, so no - it's not possible. 
As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-one-cookie) answer suggests, you may build a Flash control and use the Flash Shared Objects to share data between browsers, but that's not pretty.

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are browser specific, therefore you cant do that