# is it possible to make session for all browser

Tags: php, browser, server

I'm asking if it's possible to share cookies ?.
I mean sharing the session around the browsers on the same machine.

Comment: No, it's not possible. They don't share cookies.

Comment: If I've picked you up correctly, you want to effectively open chrome, go to some site, store data in `$_SESSION`, open IE, shudder, access the `$_SESSION` var? If so, please understand what a **massive** security issue this would be if possible. (It's not as others are pointing out)

Comment: sessions are maintained on server side unique to browsers

Comment: @ScottMcGready yees exactly

Comment: It's not possible. And any attempt to force that kind of functionality is just a massive security flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each website on browser save their own session and each browser save their own too. So the answer is you can not do this except of using cookie to access data from another browser, but i think it is not a brilliant idea to do. Just use session and cookie as the way they born, that's the best way to do.

Comment: Cookies aren't shared cross-browser.

Comment: we have ways to share cookie to browser. This is one way to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-one-cookie

Comment: Yes, flash cookies but I was talking about native cookies. You can't access flash cookies directly. You still have to check with javascript or so if the server sends a new cookie and create a new flash cookie and vice versa. That's quite a pain in the ass and I don't think there is any application which would require that.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I just want to share to him some way to access variable between browsers. Must accept that it's quite pain in the ass when use this method. Thanks for your advice bro