# Keycloak sharing login between different browsers

Tags: java, tomcat7, keycloak

we are using keycloak 3.4.2 as authentication layer for two simple java webapplications (servlet based) on tomcat 7. We have configured two clients (one for each webapplication) in the same realm. The same set of users are allowed to login in both webapplications.

Now, if user is logged in to webapp1, when he opens a new tab and open url to webapp2 he is automatically logged in to webapp2.

We would like to have such feature cross-browser.

It should work this way:
- user opens browser A and enter his credential to log in to webapp1
- user opens browser B and gets automatically logged in when the url is changed to webapp2.

We found that when we are logged in we have a JSESSIONID cookie. Is it safe to "share" the cookie ? How can we implement such feature ?

thanks

Comment: You should not. What do you want to achieve??  May be there is better way to do that.

Comment: You can have desktop login to authenticate across applications https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/authentication/kerberos.html

Comment: @Agam I want to achieve an automatic login to webapp2 from browserB IF user is already logged to webapp1 from browserA. Why not sharing JSESSIONID ?

Comment: @ravthiru we do not have kerberos. Is it the only way ?

Comment: `Why not sharing JSESSIONID?`. Think of it, have you ever seen this feature in some Internet service? Browsers are supposed to be a blackbox.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks for your  contribution. Is there any clean way to accomplish this task of "automatic" login ?

Comment: Not without hacking/cheating the browser, AFAIK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to make session for all browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430977/is-it-possible-to-make-session-for-all-browser)

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks for your opinion. So, sharing JSESSIONID is not a good idea. Do you think keycloak support this scenario ? Do we have some help from this layer ? We are currently using saml protocol but we can change to openId if it would help. Thanks.