# Why my su account logout automatically?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-allauth

My django website has been deployed and I was signed in my su account but today when I wrote my blog,I found that my su account has logouted automatically,(I didn't sign out)please tell me why and what happened?

Comment: What happen if you login in again, then close you browser then. open again. Are you still login or not.

Comment: @Aison I use another brower but it still logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the default django authentication(session authentication), your login status is depend on your cookies(stored in browser).You can have a look at [Can two different browser share one cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-one-cookie).

> Every browser maintains it's own cookies. So in general, no this is not possible.

So, it's fine.

Comment: but why any brower which I signed up shows that I logouted,otherwise I didn't use SO in general.

Comment: The browser you login will auto logout after you closed it? Please post your code about how you implement login and logout.